# Cortana Skill authentication from UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, botframework, cortana, cortana-skills-kit

I have a UWP app which has Cortana integration using Commands (VCD definitions). The app requires a user to be logged in to it (using Facebook or Google).

Now I am writing a Cortana Skill - it will offer the same functionality as the UWP app, but would work on other devices. For it to work, the user would need to log in, just like the UWP app.

I understand how the login is done in Cortana Skill (using the BotBuilder) - after login, the access & refresh tokens are somehow stored with the user's profile, so he doesn't have to login again on his other devices. I actually already built this, so the user can login with facebook/google in Cortana.

But I would like to do this from the UWP app - that is after the users logs into the UWP app, I want to take the access/refresh token and give it to some Microsoft endpoint, so that user doesn't have to login *twice* (once in UWP, second time in Cortana).

Is this possible? Is there some API I can use for this?

Answer (score 0):

The channel (Cortana) handles OAuth flow and token caching using "Connected Services". At this time, Cortana does not support single sign on or cross-client identity.  (You're UWP app and your Cortana skill are effectively two apps.)  This doesn't mean you need to use "Connected Services", but you'd be implementing around built in functionality for things like handling of refresh tokens.

Comment: Well but how can the to apps communicate? More specifically, can can they both identify the user who is invoking them? E.g. user logged in the Windows app via Facebook, how can this information be sent to the bot, that the current user (logged in with Microsoft account) logged into the app using his facebook account?

Comment: I believe OIDC is designed for that. You'd need to wire it up in your bot and clients. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc